# Обновление переменной внутри функции

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

При старте `drag` определяется длина элемента в функции `start` и присваивается заранее созданной переменной. Как присвоить эту обновленную переменную методу `left` объекта `cursorAt`?

```
 $('.pl-item').draggable({
    revert: true,
    cursorAt: {
        left: cursorShift,
        top: 12
    },
    start: function () {
        plName = $('.pl-name span', this).text();
        plColor = $('.pl-color span', this).css('background-color');
        plLength = parseInt($('.pl-info .pl-duration', this).attr('data-duration'));
        $('.pl-images', this).hide();
        $('.pl-name', this).hide();
        $('.pl-duration', this).hide();
        $('.pl-count', this).hide();
        $('.pl-color', this).hide();
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': plColor,
            'width': plLength + 'px',
            'height': '24px',
            'border': 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

Есть мысли что это нужно делать как-то через вызов функции в которой эта переменная будет обновляться, но не могу придумать как.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь, что `cursorAt` обрабатывается раньше вызова `start()`

В исходниках draggable.js

```
...
(o.cursorAt && this._adjustOffsetFromHelper(o.cursorAt));
...
if(this._trigger("start", event) === false) {
...
```

Вижу два варианта обхода:

1. Инициализация `cursorAt` в событии `create`;
2. Расчет `plLength` до инициализации `draggable()`.

Comment: А как синтаксически правильно инициализовать его в событии `create`?

Comment: Боюсь что второй вариант не подойдет, ибо елементов много, все они разной длинны. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: На самом деле я тут подумал, не пойдет и первый тоже, поскольку элементов много и у каждого нужно переделывать `cursorAt`, а в `create` мы не знаем какой из элементов будем "тянуть". Придется покопаться в исходниках и переносить функционал `_adjustOffsetFromHelper` в ваш обработчик события `start`.

Comment: Спасибо. Боюсь у меня ума не хватит побороть исходники.

Comment: @Baga Зря вы так. Дорогу осилит идущий. Там все относительно просто. Только скачайте не минимизированные исходники. Имя функции я вам указал :)